# Confidence Intervals for Normalized Random Variables

Tags: confidence-interval, independence, estimators

I think I have a pretty simple question about constructing confidence intervals for normalized random variables.

If I have i.i.d random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, ..., X_n \sim F$ for some distribution $F$, and say i have the standard mean estimator $\mu = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i} X_i $, then it is easy to construct confidence intervals for this estimator (either through Central Limit Theorem or Bootstrapping).

However, say that I now normalize each random variable. In other words, there is some function $\gamma = f(X_1, X_2, \ldots) \in \mathbb{R}^{+} $ such that I am now interested in the random variables

$$\frac{X_1}{\gamma}, \frac{X_2}{\gamma}, \ldots,\frac{X_n}{\gamma},$$

For example, $\gamma$ could be the sum, sample mean or the sample variance of the original random variables, AKA ($\gamma = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_i (X_i - \bar{\mu})^2$), where $\bar{\mu}$ is the sample mean. Then

1. is it still true that I can use CLT to construct my confidence intervals for the estimator $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i} \frac{X_i}{\gamma}$? I presume the answer is no since independence assumption is broken.
2. If CLT no longer works, would bootstrapping work? Isn't independence also required when using bootstrapping to construct confidence intervals?
3. Finally, if neither technique work, what would be the method to construct the confidence intervals for these normalized random variables?

Comment: Could you clarify what a confidence interval for "them" means?  By definition, a confidence interval is intended to include some *numerical property* of a distribution.  Which one?

Comment: I think what i mean by confidence interval here is the confidence interval for the estimator $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i} \frac{X_i}{\gamma} $

Comment: What is it estimating?

Comment: not quite sure if i answered your question, but the estimator is trying to estimate the means of the random variables $\frac{X_i}{\gamma}$ For ex., $\gamma$ could be the sample variance.

Comment: That helps.  The answer depends on $f,$ because there are extensions of the CLT that do work.  The underlying idea is that if asymptotically the $X_i/\gamma_n$ are not strongly correlated, the conclusion of the CLT still holds. You still need to be able to compute the variance of the estimator for each $n$ in order to standardize it.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense that there needs to be some conditions on $f$. The motivation here is that I see in a lot of ML tutorials that you standarize the features say using sample var., but then they go on to build confidence intervals for the mean of these normalized random variables without giving a reference on the method. Would certain versions of CLT hold if $\gamma$ here really is the sample variance?

In the worst case that the normalized random variables are strongly correlated, is it still possible to construct confidence intervals for the mean via bootstrapping or other methods?